# How to select right combobox within codedui

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am testing a winform application with VS 2017 codedui and I want select a value on a combobox. After I get record, codedui clicks on wrong combox , it clicks on first one instead of third. Btw I dont know why but codedui records combo box as WinControl instead of a WinComboBox. When I spy on combox I see no parameters for search, so how will tell codedui right combobox ? I want it to click third combobox instead of the first one

Here is the code when I get a record for the combobox

```
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinButton uIOpenButton = this.UIProMANAGEWindow2.UIMachineHistoryWindow.UIEPeriodComboBox.UIOpenButton;
        WinList uIItemList = this.UIItemWindow.UIItemClient.UIItemList;
        #endregion

        // Click 'Open' button
        Mouse.Click(uIOpenButton, new Point(9, 7));

        // Select '' in list box
        uIItemList.SelectedItemsAsString = this.ClickTimeIntervalParams.UIItemListSelectedItemsAsString;
```

Can someone tell me which value I can use from this list ?

[image: codedui capture for combobox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're having trouble with this control

```
this.UIProMANAGEWindow2.UIMachineHistoryWindow.UIEPeriodComboBox
```

This one will be a hit & try thing. First, try changing the properties of the control you're searching in UI Control Map section of your *.uitest file. 
If you can't find anything, right click the method name in UI Actions section and select "Move code to *.cs". 
Once the code goes there, you will have the option to tinker it as you like.

Here's how you can change search properties of controls:
Expand a function you defined. 
Click a step, all of controls used in it will show in right page. 
Right click any control and select "Properties"
From there, you can click "Search Properties" to modify existing or add new
[image: Manipulating Coded UI Control Properties]

I believe the properties listed in the drop down shown in second image are those we can use for finding controls.

[image: How to add new search properties or modify existing in CodedUI]

The changes we make in automatically generated file get overwritten every time code is regenerated by Coded UI. If we right click a method shown in "UI Actions" pane and move it to a map cs class, it does not get overwritten.

Comment: Naeem I know how to modify code in UImap file, but dont know what to do. Can you tell me how can I do it ? When I spy I do not see anything that I can use in search properties

Comment: And I can not see a move to code menu, where is UI Actions section ? normaly I copy paste code to UIMap.cs and recorded code still stays in UIMap.Designer.cs

Comment: Another issue, you say first change properties of the control ? How will I do that, change search and filter properties ? if so isnt this also need chaning code in UIMap.cs, whats difference between your two solutions I didnt understand that.

Comment: For example when I spy on combox box, I see Text property, can you tell me how can I add it ? since its not a search property, how can I add it ? can you provide code for that ?

Comment: I will reply shortly once I get back to office, I do see an opportunity for creating a Udemy course on this topic :D

Comment: Yes please do it I will buy it.. Btw, I see ControlName is unique per button (combobox button) but when I use ControlName as SearchProperty, codedui fails to find it. I dont know what we can use for Search Properties ? only the ones under Search when spy ?

Comment: Text property can't be used for search my friend. I've updated my answer with some screenshots and more details, I hope it helps.

Comment: I dont know why but I cant see images you added at my office pc. Btw, I can not see UI actions pane but I know UIdesigner file change everytime and I know how to modify code, I am not asking about basic things. Issue is, my recorded script doesnt use combobox, instead uses button on it when I take a record. And all combobox has same properties but buttons differ, however tool does not recognize comboboxes and not recognize butons when I added ControlName